# Save specific tweet fields in csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, twitter, tweepy

With the following part of code i open a csv file and write the text of a tweet in the first column

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time




ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

        def on_data(self,data):
            try:    
                #print data

                text = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]                


                print text 

                saveThis = str (time.time())+'::'+text 
                saveFile = open('tweets3.csv','a')
                saveFile.write(saveThis)
                saveFile.write('\n')
                saveFile.close()
            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed on data',str(e)
                time.sleep(5)

            return True

        def on_error (self,status):
            print status

auth = OAuthHandler (ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
result = twitterStream.filter(track=["zika"], languages=['en'])
```

my output looks like this

[image]

I want to store for each tweet the username of the one that makes it in column B and the number of his followers in column C. Can anybody help?

Comment: It's better to use csv library https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: could you describe how you would modify the code to add those extra columns?